# Dell 13 xps media keys are dead

Tags: multimedia

I have been looking for answers but yet not luck. I have installed Loki on a Dell XPS 13, everything seems to work but the media keys, and shortcuts. I am running single elementary OS Loki

Thanks

PS. sorry for the grammar errors. the keyboard does not help either. ;)